# RxJs - Change behavior of a stream from another stream

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs6, angular7

I'm using RxJs 6 with angular 7.

I want to draw a line from one start element to another point into a canvas. The start element is already drawn into the canvas.

I have two streams:

- One that emits the click on start element, `click$`;
- One that emits the clicks from the canvas, `canvasClick$`;

[image: two stream]

How can I define the subscriptions where to call `startDraw()` and `endDraw()`? How to manage the middle drawing state with streams?

**EDIT: a no reactive solution**

```
drawState = false;

fromEvent(elem, 'click').subscribe((e) => {
    console.log('hang', e);
    drawState = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

fromEvent(canvas, 'click').subscribe((e) => {
    if (lineBuilding) {
      console.log('stage', e);
      lineBuilding = false;
    }
  });
```

I think that there is a better way using reactive, I think that the variable `lineBuilding` is necessary and the use of stopPropagation()?